# Performance vs readability: multiple selectors vs. multiple statements in jQuery/JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing some jQuery code that hides or displays numerous table columns from a large table at the same time.  I wanted to know if it would be faster to use code like this:

```
$("selector 1, selector 2, selector 3").css("display", "none");
```

or code like this:

```
$("selector 1").css("display", "none");
$("selector 2").css("display", "none");
$("selector 3").css("display", "none");
```

So I used [jsperf.com to create a performance test case](http://jsperf.com/multiple-selectors-vs-multiple-statemtents).  With that I established that the first type of code (which uses one long string with multiple selectors) is faster than the second type of code (which hides columns one at a time) by about 53%.  However, by the time I'm done writing it, it will be borderline unreadable, looking something like this:

```
$("#table tr *:nth-child(4), #table tr *:nth-child(5), #table tr *:nth-child(6), #table tr *:nth-child(7), #table tr *:nth-child(8), #table tr *:nth-child(9), #table tr *:nth-child(10), #table tr *:nth-child(11), #table tr *:nth-child(12)").css("display", "none");
```

So my question is, which is the greater evil for jQuery/JS code--inefficient performance, or lack of readability?  My background is in Python so I tend to value readability above performance, and 53% doesn't seem like a huge drop-off in real world terms.  But on the other hand, I plan to minify my JS code once I deploy it, so it will end up not being readable anyway...though I know there are de-minifiers out there that can return my code to its original readable or unreadable form.  As you can see I can talk myself around in circles on this topic, and I'm not looking to start a debate or discussion, so I'm just posting this here in case there's a generally accepted way of handling this in the jQuery/JS community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you just have to think about alternative ways to write that code and have both worlds. For example:

```
var nth = [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

$('#table tr *')
  .filter(':nth-child('+ nth.join('),:nth-child(') +')')
  .css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Interestingly, upon benchmarking I found that this method is actually slower than the multiple-statement method.

Comment: I think you might be testing wrong...Use the "setup" field to define your initial variables otherwise you're introducing the creating of the array in the test as well. I tried in a bunch of browsers and this is way faster than multiple selectors. http://jsperf.com/6b11404dd2f0

Comment: The weird thing is, when I tested @Ian's version without the variable setup against the single-statement-with-long-selector version, they performed about the same.  When I did that with yours, it was much slower.  But when I tested your version against Ian's directly, it was slightly faster.  This was all without pre-defining variables.  But you're right, in my actual code I can define the variable just once, and if I do that in jsperform both of your guys' code is much faster than the multiple-statement one.  Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could store the selectors in an array, then join them when needing them:

```
var selectors = [
    "selector 1",
    "selector 2",
    "selector 3"
];
$(selectors.join(", ")).css("display", "none");
```

The reason your long selector works is because only one jQuery object is created, and only one browser method could be called, improving speed. I'm guessing `document.querySelectorAll` would be used, and can be passed that whole selector and return results. While jQuery would be calling `n` number of `document.querySelectorAll` methods for `n` number of `$().css` calls.

Another option, is to use the `.add` method to "improve" readability:

```
var selectors = $("selector 1");
selectors.add("selector 2");
selectors.add("selector 3");
selectors.css("display", "none");
```

Although I'm sure this will be faster than the multiple selector/`css` statements, it won't be as fast as `document.querySelectorAll`'s capability with one big selector.

Comment: Your first method seems very similar to @elclanrs's, but has noticeably better performance. In fact it performs even better than my original single statement with the long selector.  I wonder why?

Comment: @GChorn Haha that makes no sense (why it's faster than your original). Mine basically **produces** your original. But with the storage in an array and having to call `join`, I would only think it could be slower. elclanrs's solution is a little more complex; I was just trying to store/retrieve the selectors in a different way.

Comment: Oops, yeah I just noticed that when I benchmarked the two methods I gave the list variable two fewer selectors than in the original statement.  Now they're testing about the same.

Answer (score 2):

It should probably depend on how often that code gets hit (is it run once during the life of a page? is it attached to a timer or click event or something that could cause it to fire multiple times?)

I would always favor readability over efficiency UNTIL/UNLESS you identify that a certain bit of code is a bottleneck and needs to be optimized. Remember the classic programming lesson about premature optimization.

Also keep in mind your jsperf test might vary wildly across browsers and clients (especially old IEs and mobiles). Sometimes you'll see a drastic performance difference even between the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome due to differences in ECMA implementation!

Finally, a 53% difference sounds like a lot expressed as a percentage, but look at the times in ms and determine for yourself if this could be a potential bottleneck for the app.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely value readability above performance. After all you are using JS. That said you can increase the performance in readable ways as well. e.g. generating this selector with a more understandable for loop instead of an inline huge string.

Additionally with minification you should not overwrite your code. For any modifications you would still go back to your non-minified version, edit it, and minify again. The minified code is for the browser not human eyes. So any comment about its readability is irrelevant.